# Boss is making me come in after 2 weeks notice, but I have palpable anxiety being at work

Tags: quitting, stress, anxiety

So some background. I am a computer programmer working completely solo on a large project (3 months in the making, beta launch imminent).

I told them they need to hire a replacement for me, I've been telling them this for a while. However they say that are not going to hire somebody until after I have left. The attitude here is "don't address problems, just work."

There is a product launch is taking place this week, but for my position (back-end - API, DB, and Deployment) the work is not over once the product is launched.

I have already given them my two weeks notice and really, really don't like coming in to work in every day. At work, nobody talks to each other. The four of us sit in the same room and wear headphones all day. Occasionally there are conversations, but language barriers plus argumentative personalities make these a hassle that everyone prefers to avoid.

Really what they want is for everyone to just shut up and type all day long. The less clarification questions or code chat, the better.

I work better from home. I cannot stand the feeling of sitting here all day with headphones on so that my middle-manager coworkers can "verify my work". Let me stress that **nobody** looks at my code **ever** and **all my work is documented on git**.

I realize that it's "unprofessional" to just reject their "requirement" that I come in and work 8 hours every day (even though I'd get everything done from home).

However I have a lot of resentment against them for lying numerous times, time's I've been yelled at, belittled, and disrespected (by multiple management levels).

It is really hard for me to just sit down and work quietly for 8 hours.

My heart is repeatedly pounding when I get thoughts of what I ought to say them. I feel really on edge. How can I address this issue with out just quitting despite not having completed the notice period?

*Update*

A few hours after posting the question I was terminated. Basically I lost my cool and they responded by doing that. So yeah. Just FYI I guess so you can know what happened. I realize that what I should have done is just quit, rather than being argumentative to the point of getting fired.
Whoops.

Comment: Terrible situation, but what is the question? How not to come in?

Comment: what does your contract stipulate if anything? It would be very unprofessional not to show up without permission. It would also be bad to leave just before launch. But that's their problem, not yours. I'd be inclined from what you described just to walk out and ignore them unless I had contractual obligations..

Comment: Max, I edited the question because it really read more like a rant than a question.  I hope this helps.  Try to avoid details that are not directly important to answering your question.  Hope this helps

Comment: @Kilisi totally understand, thanks for adding the question at the end. I suppose it was kind of a rant.

Comment: it wasn't me, I like rants :) Venting can often solve the problem for you once you realise how absurd it is to worry over things like that and get over it.

Comment: Max please try to keep this question constructive.  I understand that you are frustrated, and if you need to rant we have a [chat] for that.

Comment: Some followup questions: Do you have a new job lined up already after your two weeks are up? Does management recognize and acknowledge your notice? Are you at all concerned about garnering a recommendation or reference from anyone at the firm? Not that they change the answer much (honestly, Joe's comment and Justin's answer are so spot on...) but they might change the minutia.

Comment: I suppose getting vacation days for your remaining 2 weeks sounds like a bad joke? I want to upvote this question as a sympathy vote to you (places like that should meet their inevitable conclusion at the hands of the free market) but I don't see a question per se.

Comment: Problem sorted. Alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its employment at will, you can leave whenever you want. Just don't expect to get paid if you leave.

You basically have two choices: go into the office every day for two weeks and get paid or leave now and don't get paid for two weeks. Your choice, pretty simple.

Some people will tell you need to serve out a notice period, otherwise your company will badmouth you if someone calls them for a reference. I would not worry too much about that. If they are going to badmouth you, working for an extra two weeks is not going to change that. As for a future employer caring whether you worked for two weeks after you quit, I would say they probably could care less, I know I would not care in the slightest.

Comment: +1 Given the circumstances, I find it unlikely that this company will give a good reference regardless of the next two weeks or not. However, they might be spiteful enough to take some kind of legal action for breaking the notice period (and contract).

Comment: @HorusKol I doubt he has a contract. Pro football players have contracts. Teachers and firefighters have contracts. Software developers do not have contracts. If you think an employment agreement is a "contract" that compels someone to work for two weeks after they quit, your understanding of state laws in the United States is imperfect.

Comment: You're right that I am not completely across US state employment laws, but how are you coming to the conclusion that any US state law is in effect here? The OP has not stated their location as far as I can tell. And while I might be using the word "contract" in its strictest legal sense - an employment agreement does carry some legal weight pretty much anywhere - it all comes down to how much the two parties in the agreement want to throw it.

Comment: -1. Given the limited information hiring managers have about candidates, finding out they left without giving notice is a black mark and can easily disqualify someone. It's simply a very unprofessional thing to do and speaks volumes about a candidate's professional values. Most managers will wonder if the candidate would do the same to them if hired and wouldn't take the risk unless it was an otherwise stellar candidate.

Answer (score 5):

You've survived for at least 3 months in this job under these conditions.  You've got less than 2 weeks to go.  Unless you are saying that going in is endangering your health, your future self will be grateful to your current self if you stick it out these last few days.  Particularly when you have a clear end in sight.

If you stop coming in to work, you're effectively turning 2 weeks notice into an immediate resignation.  That might make you happy now but it probably won't be great for you in the future.  If you finish out your 2 weeks notice, it's much more likely that your current boss will give a positive reference (or at least won't give a negative one) if asked.  If you finish out your 2 weeks notice, you can honestly tell future interviewers that you worked through a successful deploy and acted professionally even under duress.  On the other hand, if you leave abruptly just before the go-live, you're inevitably going to get the lion's share of the blame for anything that goes wrong and it is unlikely that you'll be getting positive or even neutral references.  You may not want to work with these people again but the world tends to be rather small and someone that you do want to work with in the future may well know one of the people you work for now.  Making enemies of them now after everything you've gone through seems counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks, I added a small follow up question (see edit). Do you think it'd work against me to demand an apology for prior behavior?

Comment: @maxpleaner - I can't imagine what you would hope to gain from that.  You've already resigned.  If you thought your boss would see the error of his ways and apologize, you would have asked that before resigning.  He won't apologize, you won't feel any better, and you'll just provoke one more confrontation.  You've survived at least 3 months.  You have less than 2 weeks to go.  Just keep your head down and celebrate when you're finally done.

Answer (score 0):

You've already decided to leave so I'm assuming you have another job waiting. My guess is you aren't going to ask these people for any favors, so do what you must to keep your sanity.

Let them know you will finish the project, but it will only be from home. They can lie about you, belittle and disrespect you, but they'll be doing it while you're at home.

It's up to you to determine the consequences and whether or not they're worse than staying in the office.

Comment: i don't have another job lined up. I don't really care that much, I really dislike this job.  I don't need a lecture about that point either.